# openni_camera compilation error

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to compile openni_camera with rosmake, but an error occured :

XnCppWrapper.h : No such file or directory

I don't know what to do...

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51786/openni_camera-compilation-error/) by [AnSooooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3647/ansooooo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it with installing openni librairies, and including the directory openni/build/openni/Include into the CMakeList.txt of openni_camera

---

Originally posted by [AnSooooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3647/ansooooo/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0